# Why does my web service call fail when calling a different site

Tags: ajax, web-services, web

I am making a JQuery ajax call to a web service like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://WebsiteName.com/Service.asmx/LoginExternal",
        data: "{loginData: " + JSON.stringify(LoginData) + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            ... Stuff ...
        },
        error: {
            ... Error Alert ...
        }
    });
```

When I am on the actual web site, this succeeds.  When I am on localhost and use a relative path, it succeeds.  However, when I am trying to access the web site (using an absolute path) from localhost, I get the error message that the call failed.

This would seem to indicate that it is a permissions problem and I've made sure that the web.config doesn't require authentication for access to the web service but I'm not sure what else to check.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: The "thrownError" that I am getting is "No Transport" - hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 1):

Being an unsecured scripting logic, ajax requests made using JavaScript (or JQuery) are stucked on same host, protocol and port, due to unauthenticated and unencrypted requests.

A method for passing requests to a different host, you must implement a bridge service written  in a secure language (ex. Java), deployed on same host that passes your requests further to your services, and then passes response to your ajax call.

Your ajax call will be on the bridge service then.